# Modify a copy script to retain the formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have a copy script that works perfectly, with the exception to losing my formatting when it runs.  I lose the horizontally and vertically centered text, cell background color (for conditions), all of my borders, and any text effects (bold/underline/italic).  For adding uniform borders, I use

```
Range("CSResults").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

While this works, not all of the borders are the same thickness and the cell background color varies depending on the contents of the cell.

I need to modify my current script to keep the formatting.

## Copy Script

```
Dim SectionCS As Long, NextRow As Long, TotalRows As Long

 Sheets("CS Results").Activate
 Range("CSResults").Select
 Selection.AutoFilter
 Range("CSResults").Clear
 For SectionCS = 1 To 13 '36

    NextRow = Sheets("CS Results").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next empty row

    Sheets("Function Test Procedure - CS").Activate

    TotalRows = Range("CSSec" & SectionCS).Rows.Count

    Sheets("CS Results").Range("A" & NextRow).Resize(TotalRows, 14).Value = _
        Range("CSSec" & SectionCS).Columns("A:N").Value

 Next SectionCS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not technically copy/pasting, you're setting values equal. To paste the data and the format, use `pasteSpecial`:

```
Range("CSSec" & SectionCS).Columns("A:N").Copy
With Sheets("CS Results").Range("A" & NextRow).Resize(TotalRows, 14)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

That should work, just double check the copy range is accurate.

Comment: Run-time error '424': Object required.  It threw an error at Range("CSSec" & SectionCS).Columns("A:N").Value.Copy.

Comment: @Gerasimos.Zap - Ah, sorry - just take out `.Value` (I'll edit my post).